# How to compute (negative binomial) distribution PDF and CDF in C++?

Tags: c++, random

STD has many distributions, that apparently are used to generate pseudo random variables, see e.g. below code that generates and outputs some negative binomial distributed numbers.

Now this *might* mean that internally, there is code that computes the CDF and or PDF of the negative binomial distribution, i.e. the probability that the random variable takes on a certain value, e.g. 6. Is there a way to output that probability? If yes, how? I know I could run my own code for that, but I'd rather not do that if it there is some way to get the probabilities from std.

If possible, same question for other distributions, e.g. CDF of gamma distribution.

```
int main()
{
   std::negative_binomial_distribution<int> negBin{ 5,0.5 };//Negative binomial distribution
   std::mt19937 RNG(260783);//Random generator
   for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; i++)
   {
        std::cout << negBin(RNG) << std::endl;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can find the probability for standard distributions using the formula for the pmf. See [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution) for negative binomial. And, see [Inverse transform sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling) to learn how one can generate samples following a given distribution. I don't know which method the std random is using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard doesn't specify how an implementation should implement the distribution, other than that sampling from it should take *an amortised constant* number of samples from the Generator.

[None of the members](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/negative_binomial_distribution) provide either the CDF or PDF

Answer (score 0):

> might mean that internally, there is code that computes the CDF and or PDF of the negative binomial distribution, i.e. the probability that the random variable takes on a certain value, e.g. 6. Is there a way to output that probability?

In general, no, sampling does not require to know PDF and/or CDF, see f.e. Marsaglia method(s) to sample normally distributed RV.

I could propose to take a look at GNU Scientific Library, it has sampling methods as well as PDF and CDF for negative binomial:
https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/The-Negative-Binomial-Distribution.html

Comment: Thanks. I actually ended up using boost, which also has the desired functionaty. Btw I was well aware that sampling does not necesarily require the probs (hence "might"). But since I found on the internet that the boost library, which has similar syntax, does provide the PDF function, I thought I might just have missed something.